# Delete every VM including Resources Group in Azure

Tags: bash, azure, command-line-interface, azure-cli, azureportal

I am trying to make a bash script to delete every VM with it's associated Resources group available in all of the subscriptions. A one liner code.

So, far I have made is this:

`` for i in `az account list --query "[].{id:id}" --output tsv`; do az account set --subscription $i; VMS=`az vm list --query [].name --output tsv`; tLen=${#VMS[@]} ; for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ )); do RG=`az vm list --query [$i].resourceGroup --output tsv`;  az vm delete --ids $(az vm list -g ${RG} --query "[].id" -o tsv) --yes --no-wait ; az group delete --name ${RG} --yes --no-wait; done ; done ``

Well, it works, but not perfectly. It left some of the VM's and it's associated resources group. So, I thought to upload the code here on stack-overflow. Well, It may be useful for someone and I need some help also.

So, can somebody help me? Please review my code, I am got so good at coding. I need some expert advice here. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Instead of deleting the VM and the containing resource group separately, you can simply delete the resource group. That will delete the VM as well. No need to first delete the VM and then delete the resource group.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for the tip man. I tweaked my code and now it works perfectly. I will be posting the code in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked my code and now this code works perfectly as I wanted.
This code deletes every Resources group available in every azure account subscription.

```
for i in `az account list --query "[].{id:id}" --output tsv`; do az account set --subscription $i; for j in `az vm list --query [].resourceGroup --output tsv`; do az group delete --name $j --yes --no-wait; done ; done
```

It works with both Powershell and Bash:

```
echo 'for i in `az account list --query "[].{id:id}" --output tsv`; do az account set --subscription $i; for j in `az vm list --query [].resourceGroup --output tsv`; do az group delete --name $j --yes --no-wait; done ; done' > deletevms.sh && bash deletevms.sh
```